# Workflow correlation on collection

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I have below workflow

1. Receive activity

1a. Create collection of the documents

1. Send activity (send the collection of document ids)
2. Receive activity (CorrelationHandle-single document Id)

2.Send activity

I am sending the collection of correlation handles in first send activity and in the 2nd receive activity I want the correlation handle as single document Id.

Currently, I have implemented the correlation for 1 workflow to 1 doc id but now I want correlation for 1 workflow to many doc ids.

Answer (score 0):

### Path of the Single Key

Okay, this isn't going to work quite like you have it currently because correlation works off of a single key. So, unless you can take all of those document id's and build one key that can then be reconstructed by subsequent callers you'll have to go down a different path.

### Path of Child Services

The path I would recommend is to have a primary workflow that iterates through the id's and spawns child workflows that persist as soon as they are started -- correlating on a document id that is passed to them. At this point, the calling entity would be calling a different endpoint that is available and hosting many instances (one for each of the id's) allowing correlation to work as expected.